# Unprotect workbook without password

Tags: excel, vba

I have a popular VBA code to unprotect a worksheet, but I am still running into the issue that the Workbook is protected.

```
Sub PasswordBreaker()
'Breaks worksheet password protection.

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim l As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer, i3 As Integer
    Dim i4 As Integer, i5 As Integer, i6 As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 65 To 66: For j = 65 To 66: For k = 65 To 66
    For l = 65 To 66: For m = 65 To 66: For i1 = 65 To 66
    For i2 = 65 To 66: For i3 = 65 To 66: For i4 = 65 To 66
    For i5 = 65 To 66: For i6 = 65 To 66: For n = 32 To 126
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Chr(i) & Chr(j) & Chr(k) & _
        Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & Chr(i3) & _
        Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
    If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then
        MsgBox "One usable password is " & Chr(i) & Chr(j) & _
            Chr(k) & Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & _
            Chr(i3) & Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
         Exit Sub
    End If
    Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
    Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add the VBA code.

Comment: Newer protection is based on encryption which cannot be easily removed.

Answer (score 28):

Try the below code to unprotect the workbook.  It works for me just fine in excel 2010 but I am not sure if it will work in 2013.

```
Sub PasswordBreaker()
    'Breaks worksheet password protection.
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim l As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer, i3 As Integer
    Dim i4 As Integer, i5 As Integer, i6 As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 65 To 66: For j = 65 To 66: For k = 65 To 66
    For l = 65 To 66: For m = 65 To 66: For i1 = 65 To 66
    For i2 = 65 To 66: For i3 = 65 To 66: For i4 = 65 To 66
    For i5 = 65 To 66: For i6 = 65 To 66: For n = 32 To 126
    ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Chr(i) & Chr(j) & Chr(k) & _
        Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & Chr(i3) & _
        Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
    If ThisWorkbook.ProtectStructure = False Then
        MsgBox "One usable password is " & Chr(i) & Chr(j) & _
            Chr(k) & Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & _
            Chr(i3) & Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
         Exit Sub
    End If
    Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
    Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If anyone is interested in what has changed between the two https://gist.github.com/tobya/e144806a4e3974ec4852/revisions

Comment: Does this still work for 2016? I have a excel file with one worksheet that prompts for the password, but you click on cancel and all good...

Comment: How is this supposed to remove workbook (file) protection, when it requires access to this file's VBA - as it uses ThisWorkbook?

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk VBA protection is separate from workbook protection.  VBA protection is a separate issue and not what this question is about.

Comment: Worked well for me with 2013, but took some random clicking as well. After running the script, I "protected" the workbook with the password received from the pop-up, then unprotected it again and now all sheets are unlocked

Comment: worked for me in Professional Plus 2016. older code also worked but only for worksheets but this one worked to unlock the structure. I can now add new worksheet. :)

Comment: How does it work? Is it a "bug" ? How on earth someone thought of this solution? Just curious..

Comment: It didn't work on my Excel 2016, so i did a workaround. Saved the file as `.xls` and used the code. Then saved back to `.xlsx`. Note that some funcionalities are lost and if there are more than 65,536 rows, those rows that exceed the max that .xls files support will be lost!

Comment: An old thread, but seeing as it's appeared at the top of the list - @RyszardJędraszyk if you change the procedure name to `Sub PasswordBreaker(wrkBk as Workbook)` and all the `ThisWorkbook` references to `wrkBk` you can put the code in a different file and have it break the password on your referenced file.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook but to pass `wrkBK` you need to set it first but you can't set it without the workbook being open?

Comment: @findwindow. The code isn't for passwords to open the workbook. It just unlocks sheet protection.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Ah ok. The same method should work for workbooks too if one can set a workbook without having to open it first.

Answer (score 5):

No longer works for spreadsheets *Protected* with Excel 2013 or later -- they improved the pw hash.  So now need to unzip .xlsx and hack the internals.