# Unlock password protected Workbook using VBA or Python

Tags: python, vba, excel

I have a workbook name m.xlsx, but it's password protected and I've forgotten the password. How can I open it or un-protect it?

The following code does not work:

- [Unprotect workbook without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970393/unprotect-workbook-without-password)
- [I need the command to unprotect an Excel file from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556751/i-need-the-command-to-unprotect-an-excel-file-from-python)

It ask for password when opened, and the above code does not unlock the workbook.

So, I want to put this code in a new workbook and then link my excel file with a code in place of THISWORKBOOK. Is there a way to put the m.xlsx file path without opening it (as opening of file needs password), and then run this code to unprotect the m.xlsx file?

Or is there any better way to  unprotect workbook in VBA or Python programming? I have checked some Python code but they are opening the file and that is where the problem is.

Comment: The above VBA code works for sheet protection, not workbook protection. The python code only works if you know the password. Do you know the password, or do you want to *crack* the password?

Comment: you should be able to use `Workbooks.Open(Filename:= "C:\....", Password:="pw")`, when you open it through python, but im not really understanding what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Your question explanation is ambiguous; please try to explain again what you need.

Comment: Sorry for making confusion, I wish to know the forgotten password if possible or remove protection from the workbook so that it can be opened.  "workbooks.open(filename:="",Password:="pw")" does not work when the password is unknown. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unlock any locked Excel Sheet when password is forgot without Software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45520121/how-to-unlock-any-locked-excel-sheet-when-password-is-forgot-without-software)

Answer (score 3):

Since the extension is xlsx it's the Microsoft Excel Open XML Format. That is essentially a .zip file.
Try this:

1. Copy the original file to a new folder so you don't tamper the original
2. Rename the file to a .zip extension
3. Extract the content with winzip or the like
4. In the extracted content, open xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml, preferably as a text file with notepad or the like
5. Search for  <sheetProtection
6. Remove all from  <sheetProtection to and including the terminating />
7. Save the content as a .zip
8. Rename to .xlsx

Password gone

Answer (score -2):

Open with libreoffice and will not need a password. Get what you need and put in a new file.

I think is the best option.

Comment: libreoffice didn't work for me for a locked .xls file