# Error 1004 error defined by application or object

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the font color of a cell using VBA. The reason why I can't change it directly in excel is because the worksheet is protected and I do not have the password. The cell I want to change is not blocked ( I can type in it).

In the Worksheet code I have tried using changing the color but the error 1004 always pops up when it is going to activate the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
  Range("B25").Font.Color = vbWhite
End Sub
```

I want the code to work so the cell Font is always white no matter what is typed in it

Comment: Instead of using `Range("B25")` use Target to affect the cell you are changing. May be `Range("B25")` is protected

Comment: Do you have any other code? I tried that in a worksheet, and did not receive any error. ...Wait, are you trying to add this code to change the font on a protected worksheet?  AFAIK you can't do that if it's protected.  EDIT: You are trying to change a specific cell, `B25`. As @YasserKhalil stated, change that to `Target` and, assuming the cell you *are* changing isn't locked, it should work.

Comment: i don't think you can do that, you have to unprotect the sheet, because in a protected sheet, those options are not available.

Comment: OP says that cell is not locked...

Answer (score 0):

> *The reason why I can't change it directly in excel is because the worksheet is protected and I do not have the password.*

Then VBA code can't change it either.

You can try [hash-colliding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33020536/1188513) the password and, if you're lucky, you'll be able to unprotect the sheet (note: that link is hash-colliding *workbook* protection - you'll want to tweak it a bit to crack *worksheet* protection) with a password that produces the same hash as the actual password.

If you're unlucky, well... you're out of luck.